# Hello All I am very new at coding and any help would be greatly appreciated. Trying to insert Time,delta into MySQL

Tags: python

When I run the code from the command line I get the right values showing which is 0:00:15 and continues to count when contact closed. But when I try to insert into MYSQL it returns a 0 or 1.  Like I said extremely new with code any help would be great.  I am not even sure the python code is written right to enter the proper data into the table

#! /usr/bin/env python3

```
      import time, os, socket, datetime, random, mysql.connector
      import RPi.GPIO as GP

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "Emon",
    passwd = "a password",
    database = "abc"
 )

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
start_time = time.time()

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

while True:

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

    if GPIO.input(7) == 1:
            print (datetime.timedelta(seconds=round(elapsed_time)), "on")
            os.system("echo 1 >/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness")
    else:
            print (datetime.timedelta(seconds=round(elapsed_time)), "off")
            os.system("echo 0 >/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness")

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    sql = "INSERT INTO SensorData(Type, Value, EnterDate) values ('runtime', %s, %s)"


    val = (GPIO.input(7), now)

    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Just a quick note to say that even though it's on your local machine it's generally not advisable to include any passwords here. I've edited it out.

Comment: Could you show how you're querying the database and how the result comes back?

Comment: how did you define columns in database? You could get your query and test directly in database using standard program `mysql` or tools like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)